# Inbox updates only for answers to my questions

Tags: support, global-inbox

I unsubscribed from the general daily email updates. Yet, I still wish to get updates if my own questions get answers.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Have you tried `https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/user/<your ID>/responses`? (Though it includes comments that are addressed to you too)

Comment: hmm, so if i hear you guys correctly, you are saying that there's a way to filter out the emails i receive by way of a setting, so that i only receive the things related to my questions, rather than get all the other promo stuff from stack exchange? @jfs, thank you for the URL-- is it something i ought to copy-paste into a new browser window? i can't do that if the <your ID> should be specific to my account though... but i am not sure how else to get there?, and i am confused about the "stackoverflow" being different than "stackexchange"--do i get there somehow from here? thanks for your help!

Comment: if you don't know what an rss feed is or how to get your stack overflow id, ask a separate question.

Comment: jfs, your reply only confused me more. :(

Answer (score 1):

No, there is not for just receiving answers specifically.

You can subscribe to get notifications on *all* inbox messages, which includes comments, etc. too.

I think a filter on activity on your questions specifically isn't a bad idea. (Just when receiving answer is in my opinion, you should be a little more interested in your own posts)